# In Rust, how to create pipeline processing with multiple libraries taking a Read and a Write?

Tags: rust, io, closures

Working with text streams, I'm using aho_corasick crate which allows efficient replacement of many strings in linear time on streamed text. Its interface for streams consists mainly of the following function :

```
aho_corasick::ahocorasick::AhoCorasick
pub fn stream_replace_all<R, W, B>(&self, rdr: R, wtr: W, replace_with: &[B]) -> io::Result<()>
where
    R: io::Read,
    W: io::Write,
    B: AsRef<[u8]>,
```

Now,  there is another processing which I'd like to apply to each chunk. My library also takes a Reader and a Writer and applies its own processing (although I can change the interface if necessary)

Question is, is it possible to somehow execute both functions in a pipeline, so that a chunk is processed twice ? In other words, I need to have a Writer of step1 to become sort of Reader of step2

I've tried adding a `FnMut` param to my library to add the possibility to postprocess or preprocess each chunk, but I can't figure out how to have the above AhoCorasick's function to use it.

Comment: You can always use `Vec<u8>` as the writter of step 1, and use it as the reader of step 2; are you asking for something more efficient?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Indeed, I'd like an efficient solution. How would that work with dynamically sized Vec if for example step 1 processing is faster than step 2 ? Would it continuously grow in memory until eventually step1 finishes, before step2 is able to process it ?

Comment: With a `Vec` you cannot execute them in parallel, only one after the other.

Comment: Yeah I meant in sequence (that's my goal). First processing is writing to Vec, second is reading from it. If the first processing is significantly faster, more writing will happen before reading, so the memory would grow right ? (Actually I'm not even sure if reading is consuming it)

Comment: Oh by "cannot execute them in parallel" you mean that step1 has to complete before step2 is able to begin ? That would defeat the point of streaming for me, if possible I'd like parallel processing (sequential processing for each chunk, but parallelized in a sense that next step should take over the chunk once it passes the first)

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant.

Comment: Can the second step process the data in chunks? If yes, for each chunk the first step is outputting, we can invoke the second step on it separately.

Comment: Second step is my own lib, so we can change the interface to work with chunks directly, yes. The first step however is an existing crate and predefined function - how could we obtain the processed chunk to work with from it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your second step can handle the data in chunks, you can write your own little helper that will connect the steps:

```rust
use std::io::{self, Read, Write};

pub struct Intermediate<Step2, W> {
    step2: Step2,
    final_output: W,
}

impl<Step2: FnMut(&[u8], &mut W) -> io::Result<()>, W: Write> Write for Intermediate<Step2, W> {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        self.write_all(buf)?;
        Ok(buf.len())
    }

    fn write_all(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> io::Result<()> {
        (self.step2)(buf, &mut self.final_output)
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> io::Result<()> {
        self.final_output.flush()
    }
}

pub fn two_steps<
    R: Read,
    W: Write,
    Step1: FnOnce(R, Intermediate<Step2, W>) -> io::Result<()>,
    Step2: FnMut(&[u8], &mut W) -> io::Result<()>,
>(
    input: R,
    step1: Step1,
    step2: Step2,
    final_output: W,
) -> io::Result<()> {
    let intermediate = Intermediate {
        step2,
        final_output,
    };
    step1(input, intermediate)
}
```

Comment: It took me 4 times longer to understand and apply your code than for you to write it, but I'm happy to confirm that it works as expected. Thank you so much !